# Django - MySQL doens't work with python 3.4.3 on osx 10.9.5

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, mysql-python

I'm building a web application that needs to use a mySql database. I created a database in mysql workbench. When i try to run the command for django :

'python manager.py runserver'

i get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

When i try to install MySQLdb (for python 3.4.3) via 'pip install mysql-python' i get following error :

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/cg/_w0sc5ms4hj3k5rcrf2mfm500000gn/T/pip-build-5qbm_4en/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/var/folders/cg/_w0sc5ms4hj3k5rcrf2mfm500000gn/T/pip-build-5qbm_4en/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/cg/_w0sc5ms4hj3k5rcrf2mfm500000gn/T/pip-build-5qbm_4en/mysql-python
```

Answer (score 3):

Read about `MySQL-python` on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5):

> MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release. PyPy is supported.

If you want to stick to Python 3.x you'll need to use [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient)